# Badge showing in available list, even after completing the criteria

Tags: bug, badges

I would like to know about the badge **Curious**. As per the criteria I have asked 5 questions in 5 different days. But I didn't receive this badge, it's still showing in my available list.
See the screenshot below.

[image]

Is it a `bug`?